# system.linq groupby more than one element

Tags: c#, linq

How do I select using groupby over more than one element?
something like

```
Docs.GroupBy(x => x.FieldA, x.FieldB )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use anonymous type object:

```
Docs.GroupBy(x => new {x.FieldA, x.FieldB} )
```

Comment: @rails it will work with any type of fields. Anonymous types have default Equals and GetHashCode implementations, which check all properties of type

Comment: I know. 15 minutes time limitation on answer mark. You answer too quick :-)